# Literal description of object type

Tags: vb.net, types, interface, arcgis

VB2010 with ArcObjects. Im having a problem recalling how to do this. I can test for an object type and then do something if it is the proper type. All else I want to display a message with the type that is not supported. So I have:

```
Dim pRasRenderer As IRasterRenderer
pRasRenderer = pRasterLayer.Renderer
If TypeOf pRasRenderer Is IRasterClassifyColorRampRenderer Then
  'process the layer
Else
   Debug.Print "Type not supported: " & pRasRenderer.ToString
End If
```

If not supported the print statement should read

```
       "Type not supported: IRasterStretchColorRampRenderer"
```

or any of the other types that I do not process. But All I get back is

```
       "Type not supported: System.__ComObject"
```

I tried GetType() and TypeName. Just cant remember if I can do this or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With COM, the type isn't `IRasterStretchColorRampRenderer`, it's some COM type that (most likely) implements quite a few distinctly different interfaces.  Given that you're working from .NET, you'll get `__ComObject` any time you try to access the "type" of the object directly.

The actual "type" of the object which implements `IRasterStretchColorRampRenderer`, for example, is more than likely a native implementation of a COM CoClass.  As such, you'll never get a "managed" type name from .NET code for this.

Unfortunately, this means that you're best solution is likely to report that the type passed in is not supported *without* trying to report the actual type passed into the method.  This would likely be something like:

```
Debug.Print "Type not supported: Current layer is not using a Classify Color Ramp Renderer"
```

Comment: I think I am starting to see that. The definition here is as you stated http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IRasterRenderer.htm with different coclasses. I'll just put the generic message.

Comment: @sinDizzy Yeah - the only option would be to check individual types, which is going to be pretty painful.